# Iterate through array for each value in comma separated string

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an array of colors.

```
Black[0]
White[1]
Blue[2]
Green[3]
Red[4]
Purple[5]
Orange[6]
Pink[7]
Silver[8]
```

There is a for loop that iterates for the count of the array of colors and compares to a string that is passed in. In this case it is a single color in the string.

```
private ushort? FindColor(SomeObject colorArray, string name)
{
    for (ushort i = 0; i < colorArray.Count; ++i)
    {
        SomeObject someObject = colorArray[i];
        try
        {
            if (someObject.Name == name)
                return i;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

If the string name matches the color at [i] then it returns the array number where found.

What needs to happen is the name is going to be a comma separated string of colors. So it could be `Red,Purple`.

What I'd like to do is go through the colorArray and find out if each of the split string colors are found in the array beside each other.
So in this case Red is found at 4 and Purple is found at 5. Since they are beside each other I'd like to return 4. Otherwise, if the 2 colors are not found beside each other then just return null.

```
private List<string> GetColors(string colorName)
{
    if (colorName == null)
        return new List<string>();

    string[] parts = colorName.Split(',');
    return parts.Select(p => p.Trim()).ToList();
}

private ushort? FindColor(SomeObject colorArray, string name)
{
    var colors = GetColors(name);

    for (ushort i = 0; i < colorArray.Count; ++i)
    {
        SomeObject someObject = colorArray[i];
        try
        {
            ????
            for(int j = 0; j < colors.Count; j++)
            {

                if (someObject.Name == colors[j])
                {
                    // found the first color of Red at [4]
                    // store in a temp variable ????

                    // back into the loop and found Purple at [5]
                    // Purple at [5] was found to be beside Red at [4] so return [4]

                    return i; // i in this case would be 4

                    // if the colors are not found beside each other then
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Can anyone recommend the best method to check for a case like this?

Comment: It's definitely an odd requirement - I'd expect to return a list of all matching indexes, regardless of order passed in.  Would that be preferable, or do you specifically *want* the "only return first index" behavior?

Comment: Why is this tagged with Javascript?

Comment: @AresAvatar It was also tagged with Javascript because I figured the logic for something similar in Javascript wouldn't be that much different.

Comment: @Bobson I never thought of it that way. A list of matching indexes seems to make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might work for you

```
    private void GetColors(string colors)
    {
        string[] colorArray = new string[] { "red", "green", "purple" };

        int previousIndex = -1;
        int currentIndex;

        string[] myColors = colors.Split(',');
        foreach (string s in myColors)
        {
            currentIndex = Array.IndexOf(colorArray, s);
            if (previousIndex != -1)
            {
                if (previousIndex - currentIndex == 1 || previousIndex - currentIndex == -1)
                {
                    //do stuff here
                }
            }


            previousIndex = currentIndex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This method seemed to work best for what I needed and would be easiest to understand for other developers working with the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, returning a list of all matching indexes:

```
private IEnumerable<int> FindColor(List<System.Drawing.Color> colorArray, string name)
{
    var colors = GetColors(name);
    var colorStrings = colorArray.Select(y => y.Name.ToString()).ToList();

    return colors.Select(x => colorStrings.IndexOf(x));
}
```

Usecase:

```
FindColor(ColorList, "White,Black,Pink,Polkadot");
// Returns { 1, 0, 7, -1 }
```

You could make it a bit more efficient, probably, by returning a list of `System.Drawing.Color` from `GetColors()` instead of a list of strings, but I don't think it'd make a big difference.

---

Also, if you just wanted what you originally asked for - to return the first index of a matching sequence, you can just sort what's currently in the return statement, then spin over the list to check for gaps.  If you find a gap, return null, otherwise, return the first element.